# How do I map an endpoint to a static file in ASP. NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, routes

I am building a single page web application in ASP .NET Core which requires me to map some URLs to an endpoint which serves a specific static file called "index.html".

Currently, I used a hack solution which maps **all** URLs to the endpoint.

```
_ = app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    _ = endpoints.MapControllers();

    _ = endpoints.MapGet("/test", async context => {
        // I need some way to serve the static file in the response
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world");
    });

    // TODO replace with actual endpoint mapping
    //_ = endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
});
```

Instead, I would like to map only a specific set of URLs to the endpoint. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you just want https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#serve-default-documents ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to implement URL rewriting to rewrite URLs to index.html as well as add use default files for the "/" root URL.

```
RewriteOptions rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions()
                .AddRewrite("test", "index.html", true);

_ = app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);

_ = app.UseDefaultFiles();
```

This section of code comes **before** the UseRouting middleware call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  // ...

  services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
  {
    configuration.RootPath = "static"; // Path to your index.html
  });

  // ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  // ...

  app.Map("/yourSpaRoute", spaApp=>
  {
    spaApp.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
      spa.Options.SourcePath = "/static"; // source path
    });
  });

   // ...     
}
```