# Blazor WASM Route Post Request to index.html

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a Blazor WASM app set up using the Visual Studio Template. My routing in the Startup.cs file for the Server project looks like this:

```
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html",);
});
```

This has been working great and serving the wwwroot/index.html file from my Client project any time I make a GET request a routes that I don't have a controller for. The Blazor framework in the Client project takes it for there. However, I now need to support returning the index.html file from both a GET or a POST request to endpoints in my app that I don't have a controller for. I'm having a really hard time figuring out how to set this up. I have tried the [EndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapPost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.endpointroutebuilderextensions.mappost?view=aspnetcore-6.0) method and am able to return strings but don't see any good examples of using it to return files. This does not work:

```
endpoints.MapPost("*", (HttpContext context) => {
    context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
    context.SetEndpoint(null);
});
```

Although it's similar to what the framework method StaticFilesEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapFallbackToFile does: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/fc4e391aa58a9fa67fdc3a96da6cfcadd0648b17/src/Middleware/StaticFiles/src/StaticFilesEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.cs#L194

My problem is similar to this one: [How do I map an endpoint to a static file in ASP. NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62372527/how-do-i-map-an-endpoint-to-a-static-file-in-asp-net-core) but answers there don't work for my situation.

Comment: Hi @Chris, are you sure you use blazor WASM instead of blazor server app?

Comment: @Rena, yes I am quite sure it's a WASM app. The WASM and Web API parts are deployed to the same server and the Web API code handles routing requests/serving the index.html for the WASM app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more reading of the aspnetcore source and MapFallbackToFile I came up with this solution that works for me. My Server solution's Startup.Configure method has this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapPost("{*path:nonfile}", CreatePostIndexRequestDelegate(endpoints));
    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
});
```

And I added this new method to that Startup class:

```
//This method allows Post requests to non-file, non-api endpoints to return the index.html file
private static RequestDelegate CreatePostIndexRequestDelegate(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
{
    var app = endpoints.CreateApplicationBuilder();
    app.Use(next => context =>
    {
        context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
        context.Request.Method = "GET";
        // Set endpoint to null so the static files middleware will handle the request.
        context.SetEndpoint(null);
        return next(context);
    });
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    return app.Build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one way that could help you. You can tell the webserver to route any route it doesn't find to you index.html. The syntax in Nginx is

> try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;

Not sure if this will fix your issue, as I haven't tested this with Api controllers in Wasm.